# java bytecode .. replacing icosnt_ with bipush<>

Tags: java, bytecode

I am trying to understand why when I replace the iconst_5 (08) with bipush 20 (1014) it won't work. Would it be possible to set an integer other than -1 to 5 in this case?

```
A7 00 07     goto                pos.00000170
15 0E        iload               local.0E
08           iconst_5
6C           idiv
36 16        istore              local.16
2A           aload_0
2B           iload_1
15 16        iload               local.16
B7 00 E9     invokespecial       void hui.surf.I.V.A(java.io.PrintWriter, int)
84 0F 01     iinc                local.0F, 1
```

here's the decompiled snippet:

```
enter code here
{       
 i6 = paramBoolean1 ? i4 / 2 : i4 / 5;
    A(paramPrintWriter, i6);
  }
```

I need to replace the integer number 5 with 20.

If I replace 08 with 10 14 this is what the editor does:

```
A7 00 07    goto                pos.00000170
15 0E   iload               local.0E
10 14   bipush              20
36 16   istore              local.16
2A  aload_0
2B  aload_1
15 16   iload               local.16
B7 00 E9    invokespecial       void hui.surf.I.V.A(java.io.PrintWriter, int)
84 0F 01    iinc                local.0F, 1
A7 FE F3    goto                pos.0000006F
```

this is what the decompiled code looks like: (JDgui decompiler)

```
{
  i6 = paramBoolean1 ? i4 / 2 : 20;
  A(paramPrintWriter, i6);
 }
```

Comment: Well, obviously the larger instruction takes more space and hence will upset any branches across that area of the code (such as the goto at the top).

Comment: would it be possible to insert a new line on the bytecode... I am using dirtyJoe... it does not inserts new lines only edits existing.

Comment: I know nothing about "dirtyJoe".

Comment: its standalone cpp written bytecode editor.. you can edit and save the .class

Comment: Did you try to set the hex value(s) of the instruction to `10 14` (two byte values with a space between them)? Are you sure you can’t simply enter “bipush 20” into the third column?

Comment: yes.. if you replace 08 with 10 14 it doesn't work..  I think something basic goes missing.

Comment: Do your replacement, dump it the same way you did above, and show us what was dumped.  I have no idea what your "editor" is doing.

Comment: You didn’t answer my second question. What happens if just you double-click on `iconst_5` and change it to `bipush 20` in the disassembly view?

Comment: it doesn't let us edit the bytecode only the hex opcodes..  after editing you push enter to confirm

Comment: Sounds like you should look for another tool…

Comment: @HotLicks I've added the results to the main post.. pls look above. Holger do you have a suggestion? thanks

Comment: So, comparing the two listings, what do you notice?

Comment: the idiv is gone..  why???? it seems the bipush eats a line

Comment: Try first to insert an extra iconst_5 (a no-op), to check whether the jump addresses are corrected.

Comment: @JoopEggen.. the adderesses seem to be corrected if i replace iconst_5 with a nop and back..  all looks the same.

Comment: The bipush is two bytes long, the iconst_5 is only one byte long.

Comment: Just found a java written bytecode editor that worked.. it lets you insert lines and move them up/down.. and save.. and voilá... it works::::)))))  Thanks ALL!  btw.. its called reJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the instructions are different sizes, so changing it will upset all the branch offsets.

If you use Krakatau, it will replace all the numerical offsets with labels, allowing for easier editing. (Disclosure: I wrote it). Based on the comments, it looks like ReJ works too. I immagine most tools will, since it's common behavior for assemblers.

Comment: thanks:) I did browse github but do you have a link for download, is it standalone ui? sounds like its the most uptodate tool available

Comment: ops.. just read the README... mmm learning curve... I might get worthy of using it.. need time..  prefer gui :) thanks!

Comment: Sorry. One thing Krakatau is not is user friendly.